# RxJava : Reduce not working as expected

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm trying to load a user object in parallel.

```
    final User user = new User();
    final Observable<User> userObs = Observable.just("NAMES", "ADDRESSES", "CURRENT_ADDRESS")
            .flatMap(field -> getOrchestrator(user, field))
            .scan(new User(), (finalUser, event) -> {
                finalUser = event;
                return finalUser;
            });
```

Scan does emit three user object, where as the reduce does not emit any items at all? what am I doing wrong here.

```
    final User user = new User();
    final Observable<User> userObs = Observable.just("NAMES", "ADDRESSES", "CURRENT_ADDRESS")
            .flatMap(field -> getOrchestrator(user, field))
            .reduce(new User(), (finalUser, event) -> {
                finalUser = event;
                return finalUser;
            });
```

The getOrchestrator returns Observable. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the complete code snippet

```
public class Orchestrator {
    private String userId;

    public Orchestrator(final String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final User user = new User();
        final Observable<User> userObs = Observable.just("NAMES", "ADDRESSES", "CURRENT_ADDRESS")
                .flatMap(field -> getOrchestrator(user, field))
                .scan(new User(), (finalUser, event) -> {
                    finalUser = event;
                    return finalUser;
                });

        userObs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(result -> {
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        });

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

    }

    private static Observable<User> getOrchestrator(final User user, final String fieldName) {
        switch (fieldName) {
            case "CURRENT_ADDRESS":
                return new AddressOrchestrator().getCurrentAddress(user.getUserId())
                        .map(currentAddress -> {
                            user.setAddress(currentAddress);
                            try {
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                            }
                            catch (final InterruptedException e) {

                            }
                            return user;
                        });
            case "ADDRESSES":
                return new AddressOrchestrator().getAddresses(user.getUserId())
                        .map(addresses -> {
                            user.setAddresses(addresses);
                            try {
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                            }
                            catch (final InterruptedException e) {

                            }
                            return user;
                        });

            case "NAMES":
                return new NameOrchestrator().getNames(user.getUserId())
                        .map(names -> {
                            user.setNames(names);
                            try {
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                            }
                            catch (final InterruptedException e) {

                            }
                            return user;
                        });
        }
        return null;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        final Random r = new Random();
        if (r.nextInt(3) % 2 == 0) {
            return new User();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Each orchestrator returns Observable.

```
public class AddressOrchestrator {

    public Observable<List<Address>> getAddresses(final String userId) {
        return Observable.create(s -> {
            final Address currentAddress = this.getBaseAddress(userId);
            final Address anotherAddress = this.getBaseAddress(userId);
            anotherAddress.setState("NE");
            s.onNext(Arrays.asList(currentAddress, anotherAddress));
        });

    }

    public Observable<Address> getCurrentAddress(final String userId) {
        return Observable.create(s -> s.onNext(this.getBaseAddress(userId)));
    }

    public Address getBaseAddress(final String userId) {
        final Address address = new Address();
        address.setLine1("540 Caddo Lake Dr");
        address.setCity("Georgetown");
        address.setCountry("USA");
        address.setState("TX");

        return address;
    }
}


public class NameOrchestrator {

    public Observable<List<Name>> getNames(final String userId) {
        return Observable.create(s -> {
            final Name name = new Name();
            name.setName("Vanchi");
            final Name formerName = new Name();
            formerName.setName("Vanchinathan");
            s.onNext(Arrays.asList(name, formerName));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a full example. For all we know your subscription is wrong.

Comment: It seems that your stream is infinite.

Comment: While using scan, the stream does end. When using reduce, it does not emit an item. @weston Added the complete code snippet

Comment: @VanchinathanChandrasekaran yeah, that's because `scan` doesn't wait for stream completion. Can you add either `.doOnCompleted()` operator to your observable chain or `onCompleted` action to your subscription and check if it's called.

Comment: @AlexanderPerfilyev You were right. It does not end. The reason being that the AddressOrchestrator which returns a Observable of Address does not call onCompleted(), which was noted by below answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your orchestrations which you create using `Observable.create` (a big red flag unless you really know what you're doing) do not terminate. This leads to infinite streams (in the sense that a complete event is never emitted). What you need it something like

```
public Observable<List<Address>> getAddresses(final String userId) {
        return Observable.create(s -> {
            final Address currentAddress = this.getBaseAddress(userId);
            final Address anotherAddress = this.getBaseAddress(userId);
            anotherAddress.setState("NE");
            s.onNext(Arrays.asList(currentAddress, anotherAddress));
            s.onCompleted();
        });
```

Note the `onCompleted` being called. This will fix your superficial problems but you're better off getting rid of the `Observable.create` in the first place and using something like `Observable.defer`.

Comment: Can you explain how create is bad and how defer helps?

Comment: In short there are any number of ways to mess up when you use `Observable.create` which is why it's generally not recommended if you have an alternative. There's a good blog post on 'Observable.defer` [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4).

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because `scan` emits all upstream items while `reduce` will emit only if stream is completed.

Replace

```
public Observable<Address> getCurrentAddress(final String userId) {
    return Observable.create(s -> s.onNext(this.getBaseAddress(userId)));
}
```

with

```
public Observable<Address> getCurrentAddress(final String userId) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> this.getBaseAddress(userId));
}
```

and

```
public Observable<List<Address>> getAddresses(final String userId) {
    return Observable.create(s -> {
        final Address currentAddress = this.getBaseAddress(userId);
        final Address anotherAddress = this.getBaseAddress(userId);
        anotherAddress.setState("NE");
        s.onNext(Arrays.asList(currentAddress, anotherAddress));
    });
}
```

with

```
public Observable<List<Address>> getAddresses(final String userId) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> this.getBaseAddress(userId))
            .zipWith(Observable.fromCallable(() -> this.getBaseAddress(userId))
                    .map(address -> address.setState("NE")),
                    (currentAddress, anotherAddress) -> Arrays.asList(currentAddress, anotherAddress));
}
```

and change your `setAddress()` method to this

```
public Address setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
    return this;
}
```

`fromCallable()` is a better way to create an `Observable` that emits at most one element, because it handles errors and backpressure for you.